# How can the BitTorrent DHT for a specific torrent be accessed over Tor?

Tags: bittorrent

[BitTorrent.org](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html) explains that: 'BitTorrent uses a distributed sloppy hash table" (DHT) for storing peer contact information for "trackerless" torrent.' Because DHT for BitTorrent operates on UDP, it cannot be accessed via Tor as far as I am aware.

Can someone suggest any means for DHT *tracking of torrents* (not downloading the torrent!) to be used over Tor please ?

Comment: Please don't use bittorrent over Tor. It slows the network for everybody else.

Comment: For anyone else thinking of sidestepping the question rather than being constructive - I am not talking about sending torrent data, I am talking about the tracker data only.